# How to correctly pass data through JSON (CodeIgniter)

Tags: json, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass data from my model to controller and from my controller to view via JSON.

My model:

```
public function GetRecordDetails($array){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('type', $array['event_type']);
    $this->db->where('id', $array['event_id']);

    return $this->db->get('records')->result_array();
}
```

My controller:

```
public function show_record(){

    $this->load->model('records_model');
    $data = array(
        "event_id" => $_POST['id'],
        "event_type" => $_POST['type']
    );
    $msg = array();

    if(empty($data['event_id']))                            $msg['failed'] = "failed"; else
    if(empty($data['event_type']))                          $msg['failed'] = "failed"; else
    if($this->records_model->CheckForRecord($data) == 0)    $msg['failed'] = "failed"; else

    if(count($msg) == 0){
        $array['data'] = $this->records_model->GetRecordDetails($data);

        $msg = array(
            "success" => "success",
            "id" => $data['event_id'],
            "country" => $array['data']
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

and my view:

```
EVENT.show = function (id, type) {

$("#loader_" + id).html("<img src='images/loaders/loader2.gif' width='11px' height='11px' alt='loading' />");    
$("#failure").css('display', 'none');
$("#record_show").css('display', 'none');

var form_data = {
    id      : id,
    type    : type
}

$.ajax({
    url: "records/show_record",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: form_data,
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.failed){
            $("#loader_" + id).html("");
            $("#failure").fadeIn(500);
            $("#msg_area").html(data.failed);
        }
        if(data.success){
            $("#loader_" + id).html("");
            $("#record_show").fadeIn(500);
                $("#record_id").val(data.id);
                $("#record_country").val(data.country);
        }
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});

return false;
};
```

I can't receive "country" value from my array in controller. I just don't know how should I do it.

It returns for me all array from my mysql data:

```
{"success":"success","id":"38","country":[{"id":"38","type":"1","country":"1","event":"RAFAEL NADAL vs NOVAK DJOKOVIC","date":"2013-07-24 00:00:00","selection":"Novak Djokovic +2.5","odds":"1.83","result":"1"}]}
```

What should i do, to grab only one element from my array? I want that my country value be `$array['data']['country']` but if I type it in my controller I get (object Object)

Comment: `$array['data']->country`?

Comment: nope:

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/records.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 83</p>

Comment: `var_Dump($array['data'])` and see what type it is and how can you get values from it.

Comment: As I can see from json - it's array of objects. Then use `$array['data'][0]->country`

Comment: it gives me an array, but how should I take only one value from that?

{array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "35"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["country"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["event"]=>
    string(30) "RAFAEL NADAL vs NOVAK DJOKOVIC"
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2013-07-24 00:00:00"
    ["selection"]=>
    string(19) "Novak Djokovic +2.5"
    ["odds"]=>
    string(4) "1.83"
    ["result"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }}

Comment: So you don't know how to address an element in arrays?

Comment: I need only one element from all array. $array['data'] returns all array, I need only $array['data']['country'] $array['data']['country']but I can't type it like

Comment: `$array['data'][0]['country']`

Comment: tkanks murder, you helped me a alot ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have set the 'country' key in the `$msg` array to be the entire result set array.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do then the country value would actually be `$msg[country][country]`.

It would be better if when you set the `$msg` array you used `$array[data][country]` then you would retrieve the country value simply using `$msg[country]`.

I hope I understood what your problem was.

Ps. As a side issue, naming an array 'array' is probably not a great idea as it could get confusing very quickly. Name it based on what is in the array eg results.